# Returning a Javascript file through Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to return a Javascript file when a customer goes to a specific URL on my Laravel development. I will run a check against a DB table before showing the Javascript file;

1. User visits http://www.website.co.uk/account/123542/javascript.js
2. Laravel checks against the DB to see if 123542 exists as an account
3. If it exists then return javascript.js if not return error.

The javascript file will be the same no matter what URL is requested so I just need to return a JS file.

I just need to know how to return the Javascript file.

Comment: What do you mean by *return Javascript file*? Do you need to link a separate JS file *if* the ID exists? Is that it?

Comment: Yer it needs to show a javascript file when you go to http://www.website.co.uk/account/123542/javascript.js, the javascript file will be on my server and I just need to show it when the url is loaded.

Comment: Whats the thing? I mean... You just receive the request through your route, check if the account exist, if it does exists just return a view in which you include your javascript file (I am assuming that display the javascript file in browser is what you want), if it does not exist return any other view which does not include the js file.

Comment: If you know the path of the file where the code is for `javascript.js` then you could use Laravel to grab the file's contents and then echo it out onto the page and give it the appropriate `Content-Type`

Comment: Change Content-Type header to "text/javascript".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('account/{id}/javascript.js', function ($id) {

    if (/* the ID exists in the database */ === false) {
        abort(403, 'Forbidden');
    }

});
```

Did not test it, but it should abort the call if the ID is non-existent, and show the JS otherwise.

You need the check-the-database logic here of course.